# How do I automatically refresh an infinitelist in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am using InfinteList to show a list of items. This list needs to update automatically when new data is available. I want to be able to do that without the user having to pull to refresh. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean `InfiniteContainer`?

If so it has a `refresh()` method that you can invoke directly: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/InfiniteContainer.html#refresh--